# How to serialize SqlAlchemy join query to JSON?

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Can anyone help me design/find a JSON encoder that will work when using a join in my sqlalchemy query and will serialize the results in which I specify.

The query looks like so:`data = db.session.query(Post).join(Users).filter(Post.area == id, Users.id == Post.user_id).all()`

I then do a json dump like so: `json_object = json.dumps(data, cls=AlchemyEncoder)`

Traditionally I use my own JSON encoder which can be seen here:

```
class AlchemyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o.__class__, DeclarativeMeta):
            data = {}
            fields = o.__json__() if hasattr(o, '__json__') else dir(o)
            for field in [f for f in fields if not f.startswith('_') and f not in ['metadata', 'query', 'query_class']]:
                value = o.__getattribute__(field)
                try:
                    json.dumps(value)
                    data[field] = value
                except TypeError:
                    data[field] = None
            return data
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

The function it references will look something like the following:

```
 def __json__(self):
        return ['id', 'user_id', 'message', 'media', 'time_uploaded', 'lifetime', 'votes', 'area']
```

However there are columns in the table of which I join in the query that I would like to include in the JSON object I create. My JSON encoder can obviously only use columns found in the first table I query.

EDIT:

Here are what my two SQLAlchemy classes look like:

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "post"

    id = db.Column('id', UUIDType(binary=False), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column('user_id', UUIDType(binary=False), db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    votes = db.Column('votes', db.Integer)
    message = db.Column('message', db.Unicode)
    media = db.Column('media', db.Unicode)
    lifetime = db.Column('lifetime', db.Integer)
    time_uploaded = db.Column('time_uploaded', db.DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    area = db.Column('area', db.Unicode)

    user = db.relationship('Users', foreign_keys=user_id)

    def __json__(self):
        return ['id', 'username', 'name', 'profile_picture', 'message', 'media', 'time_uploaded', 'lifetime', 'votes', 'area']


class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column('id', UUIDType(binary=False), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column('username', db.Unicode, unique=True)
    email = db.Column('email', db.Unicode, unique=True)
    password = db.Column('password', db.Unicode)
    name = db.Column('name', db.Unicode)
    bio = db.Column('bio', db.Unicode)
    profile_picture = db.Column('profile_picture', db.Unicode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlalchemy put in the `select` part on the query whatever you pass to the `query` method, so if you want to get 2 classes you can do:

```
db.session.query(Post, Users).join(Users).filter(Post.area == id, Users.id == Post.user_id).all()
```

this will return an array of tuples of the Post and Users class (so you will have to change the encoder to be able to recieve tuples)

EDIT:

here is a sample to how you can change your encoder to accept tuples:

```
class AlchemyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, tuple):
            data = {}
            for obj in o:
                data.update(self.parse_sqlalchemy_object(obj))
            return data
        if isinstance(o.__class__, DeclarativeMeta):
            return self.parse_sqlalchemy_object(o)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

    def parse_sqlalchemy_object(self, o):
        data = {}
        fields = o.__json__() if hasattr(o, '__json__') else dir(o)
        for field in [f for f in fields if not f.startswith('_') and f not in ['metadata', 'query', 'query_class']]:
            value = o.__getattribute__(field)
            try:
                json.dumps(value)
                data[field] = value
            except TypeError:
                data[field] = None
        return data
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clearing it up in regards to getting two classes returned. Thanks for the encoder also! However when I use it I still get an error: `AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'username'` My `__json__` function is within the Posts class I am not sure if this is causing the issue?

Comment: Let me add to my question what the two classes look like along with the desired fields I wish to be serialized.

Comment: @Joshua You have "username" in your `Post.__json__` but you don't have a field on `Post` called `username`. Perhaps you meant to put it on `Users.__json__`?

Comment: @univerio but if I were to put it in the Users class it would be missing other columns? Such as votes.

Comment: @Joshua You seem to have a fundamentally incorrect misunderstanding of how your encoder works. Your encoder serializes `Users` and `Post` instances. When you query for `(Post, Users)` together it doesn't return some magical single instance *that has both the attributes of `Users` and `Post`*. Instead, it returns a tuple where the first element is a `Post` instance and the second is a `Users` instance. In case this still isn't clear, you need two `__json__` functions, one on `Post` and one on `Users`, that returns the fields you would like to serialize for each class, respectively.

Comment: @univerio Thanks for the explanation, you are absolutely right I really was not that sure how it was working. Thanks for the clarification, the serilization now works perfectly :) Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

now it works for Row, not tuple.

so i rewrite.

```
class AlchemyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
def default(self, o):
    if isinstance(o, Row):
        data = {}
        for obj in o:
            data.update(self.parse_sqlalchemy_object(obj))
        return data
    if isinstance(o.__class__, DeclarativeMeta):
        return self.parse_sqlalchemy_object(o)
    return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

def parse_sqlalchemy_object(self, o):
    data = {}
    fields = o.__json__() if hasattr(o, '__json__') else dir(o)
    for field in [f for f in fields if not f.startswith('_') and f not in ['metadata', 'query', 'query_class', 'registry']]:
        value = o.__getattribute__(field)
        try:
            json.dumps(value)
            data[field] = value
        except TypeError:
            data[field] = None
    return data


    return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

thank you