# JOIN Query Flask SQLAlchemy Related Tables using relationships table

Tags: mysql, flask, join, flask-sqlalchemy, relationship

I want to define two related tables which are **student** and **mentor** and their relationship has to be defined through a relationship table **student_mentor** on a database level. They have to be mapped to Flask app classes using Flask SQLAlchemy library. How can I relate the tables using Flask SQLAlchemy **relationship** and JOIN **student** and **mentor** tables during a query, (I neglected some fields of the tables).

The following are the classes of the models:

**student**:

```
class Student(db.Model, Serializer):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  #some columns...
```

**mentor**:

```
class Mentor(db.Model, Serializer):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  #some columns...
```

**student_mentor**

```
class StudentMentor(db.Model, Serializer):
  student_id = db.Column(db.Integer) # id column of student table
  mentor_id = db.Column(db.Integer) # id column of mentor table
```

I am looking forward to achieve my goal with a query of this nature:

**query**:

```
students = Student.query.order_by(desc(Student.created_at)).join(Mentor).paginate(page=1, per_page=5, error_out=False)
```

**serialization**:

```
students = json.loads(dumps(Student.serialize_list(students.items), default=str))
```

**serializer**:

```
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect

class Serializer(object):
    def serialize(self):
        return {c: getattr(self, c) for c in inspect(self).attrs.keys()}

    @staticmethod
    def serialize_list(l):
        return [m.serialize() for m in l]
```

Comment: I think you can try `secondary` parameter in relationship: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many. Similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417906/sqlalchemy-manytomany-secondary-table-with-additional-fields

Comment: @jorzel when I hit a query like in the question I am getting an error: "sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Don't know how to join to <Mapper at 0x22cbf2e62e0; Vehicle>. Please use the .select_from() method to establish an explicit left side, as well as providing an explicit ON clause if not present already to help resolve the ambiguity."

Answer (score 0):

You don't have direct relationship between `Student` and `Mentor`, so you must join using `StudentMentor` model:

```py
students = Student.query
    .join(StudentMentor, Student.id == StudentMentor.student_id)
    .join(Mentor, StudentMentor.mentor_id == Mentor.id)
    .order_by(desc(Student.created_at))
    .paginate(page=1, per_page=5, error_out=False)
```

For better joining you should use foreign keys in `StudentMentor` model:

```py
class StudentMentor(db.Model, Serializer):
  student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('student.id')) # id column of student table
  mentor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('mentor.id') # id column of mentor table
```

Comment: The result is of the form: [{'name': 'student_name', 'mentors': ['<Mentor 4>']}]. How can I jsonify Mentor information?. '<Mentor 4>' is a string.

Comment: You should define a serializer function for `Mentor`. How you serialize `Student`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022066/how-to-serialize-sqlalchemy-result-to-json

Comment: I edited my question with new additions which are serialization of my Student and the Serialize class.

Comment: You probably need to have more sophisticated serializer that handle tuples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952694/how-to-serialize-sqlalchemy-join-query-to-json